# Putting Lambdas in OR statement

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain why the second example does not work:

```
var thisWorks = true || function () {};
var thisBreaks = true || () => {};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the precedence of the various operators in ECMAScript 6 works.

There's a great explanation at http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2360 that walks through each production in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
 var thisBreaks = true || (() => {});
```

I think is related to operators priority.

```
var thisBreaks = true || (()=>{ }) ;
```

compile to javascript:

```
var thisBreaks = true || (function () { });
```

while

```
var thisBreaks = true || ()=>{};
```

compile to javascript:

```
var thisBreaks = true || ();
{ }
;
```

Try yourself here:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground